# Getting Dictionary From JSON

Tags: ios, json, nsdictionary

I am trying to get Dictionary form json, but the following code dosent seem to work. I am getting the JSON, but cannot get the dictionary from it.

```
NSString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:responseCust encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"CUSTOMER string -----################  %@", str);

if(str.length>5)
{
     SBJSON *jsonparser=[[SBJSON alloc]init];
     NSDictionary *res= [jsonparser objectWithString:str];

     NSLog(@"Contants Results %@",res);

     [jsonparser release];
     [str release];
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: use NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: Please explain yourself better.  You get a (apparently valid) JSON string, but "Contants Results" prints "(null)"?  If so, first copy/paste your JSON into an online JSON parser to check its validity.

Comment: Read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @Nitin Check my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Follow the below code

```
NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:str];

NSData * data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSError * error;

//Get json data in Dictionary
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];

NSLog(@"%@",json);
```

try this one..

Comment: hi, used your method and now i am getting this error  -JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Unrecognised leading character\" UserInfo=0x737cdf0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unrecognised leading character}"
)
But the json looks clean.

Comment: yes, the url is correct. This error gets displayed in my console.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098434/json-value-failed-in-ios   follow that link

Comment: tried, its not because of linebreaks. I really had hopes on this. Its some invisible character. I cant see it but i know its there.

Answer (score 1):

Use [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and make use of

```
+ (id)JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)data options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error to convert JSON to foundation object.
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Just try to  **Either**

```
NSDictionary *dict = [str JSONValue];
NSLog(@"%@", dict);
```

**OR**

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseCust options:nil error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", dict);
```

Comment: tried all the above methods, none seem to work. JSON is also correct , checked it on json.parser.online.fr .....

Comment: really strange, could you paste the JSON on the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
+(NSDictionary *)converJsonStringToDictionary:(NSString *)jsonString
{
    NSString *stringToConvert = jsonString;

    if (![self isObjectEmpty:stringToConvert]) {

        NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSDictionary *convertedData = nil;

        convertedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

        if (error != nil){
            DLog(@"Error converting jsonString to dictionary: %@", [error description]);
            convertedData = nil;
        }
        else if ([convertedData isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            DLog(@"The converted data is of kind NSDictionary");
        }
        else if ([convertedData isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
            DLog(@"The converted data is of kind NSArray");
            convertedData = nil;
        }
        else{
            DLog(@"The converted data is not NSDictionary/NSArray");
            convertedData = nil;
        }
        return convertedData;
    }
    else{
        DLog(@"The received jsonString is nil")
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, try adding the encoding...

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSLog(@"dict: %@", jsonDict);
```

Check here for [some samples on how to handle json on objective-c](http://emiliolopezmartinez.wordpress.com/2013/06/04/nsjsonserializer-sample/)